# Which system modelling notation for showing interconnections and internal logical structures?

Tags: architecture, modeling, notation, interaction

I am trying to model a collection of systems, their various interconnections, as well as their internal logical structures, as a message is passed through them, initiated by an actor.

I have been using BPMN 2.0 notation with [Yaoqiang Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bpmn/).

However I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, or even using the right notation.

[System example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9741.png)

Is this correct, if not, can you recommend an alternate notation or method of displaying the systems?

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having multiple swimlanes without lines linking between them. Some swimlanes end with exclusive to end xor intermediary event with text explaining which function, procedure or system it's calling. Next swimlane starts with green orb "Start event".

It seems really effective, would recommend this style to others.

Answer (score 0):

BPMN is used for documenting business processes. This is meant to show behaviour without going down to system details. Your system example shows activities, not systems.

I would approach this in three steps.

1. Model the business process (as you already started). BPMN is OK for this, UML use cases may be useful as well.
2. Model the systems as such. With modelling a collection of systems and interconnections, you are looking for static structure. This can be documented using UML component diagrams.
3. Model the message passing. The message passing again is behaviour, this time tied to concrete systems and interfaces. Modelling can be done e.g. as UML activity diagrams or UML sequence diagrams.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying I should continue using this notation for the system process and intereconnection info (as shown)?

Comment: No. I say that you should use BPMN for business processes. Use e.g. UML fpr systems and interface info. I don't see systems and interfaces in your example.

Comment: I ended up having multiple swimlanes without lines linking between them. Some swimlanes end with exclusive to end xor intermediary event with text explaining which function, procedure or system it's calling.  Next swimlane starts with green orb "Start event". It seems really effective, would recommend this style to others.